# How to enable Zend Optimiser+ with Batcache

Tags: php, server, cache, apc

I am using [Batcache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/batcache/) with [APC Object Cache Backend](https://wordpress.org/plugins/apc/) so far.  A lot of posts on internet claiming that using Zend Optimizer instead of APC would reduce CPU and memory usage.  I could enable Zend Optimizer on my server. But I haven't found a plugin or workaround to make Batcache works with Zend Optimizer.

Is that a "Zend Optimizer Object Cache Backend" for Batcache?  How to make Batcache use Zend Optimizer?

Thank you.

Comment: This may be relevant to your question: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/looking-ahead-to-php-55-zend-optimizer-the-end-of-apc. Specifically, "Zend Optimizer has time and again not been proven any faster [than] APC."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Optimizer+, or rather [OPcache](http://php.net/opcache) module as it is formally called included in PHP, is purely opcode cache. It doesn't implement key-value store and cannot be used as object cache back-end in WordPress.